# Eisvogel Template for LaTeX

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I really like this template for the documents created with pandoc but I only want the style of this template. I have searched on google for eisvogel latex template but haven't got any.
It basically converts the markdown files to latex with respect to this template.

How can I use this style for my latex files ?

The link for the template is can be seen here : https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template
[image: Basic Example]

Comment: There is no latex template, but you can generate a latex document with pandoc and work with that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you take the folders in the examples part of that [template](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template), and convert the document.md to a tex file using

`pandoc document.md -o example1.tex --from markdown --template eisvogel --listings`

This produces a tex document and you then run `pdflatex example1.tex`.

From that tex template you just created, you can edit and modify as required.

The `title-page-custom` folder will create a latex template with a title page, for example.